# Subsetting data coming from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a model which collects data in my ASP.NET MVC app:

```
namespace myapp.Models
{
    [Table("mytable")]
    public partial class mytbl
    {
        // column specifications
    }
}
```

but this model takes all rows of the selected table. I want to add some filter rules. In an SQL query it's look so;

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE mycol = 2 OR mycol = 3
```

in above example I typed 2 and 3 by hand but I have a text file toshow.txt (located at wwwroot) the contents of the toshow.txt file is;

```
2
3
```

How can I subset the data according to the text file ?

I'm not super familiar with ASP.NET MVC app development. Sorry if my question doesn't make sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you want to read values from a text file and use them as parameters in a SQL query? Is that correct? If not, could you clarify the problem?  If that is the problem, then what difficulties are you facing?

Comment: Load the values from your text file, then use a `Where(x => values.Contains(x => x.MyCol))`...  This will build an `IN()` clause which will produce the results you are looking for.

Comment: @StevePy what about a column which consists of integers and `values` integer array also ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to

1. read the file
2. convert `string`s read from the file to `int` values
3. filter the data in the database

The below should at least get you started:

```
// get filename and read the file
string fileName = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "toshow.txt");
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

// parse values in file to List<int>
List<int> filter = lines.Select(line => int.Parse(line)).ToList();
// could also be written lines.Select(int.Parse)

// filter your DB
var filteredResult = _context.MyTable.Where(x => filter.Contains(x.MyCol));
```

Where `_env` is an `IWebHostingEnvironment` and `WebRootPath` maps to the wwwroot directory. You may need to use `ContentRootPath` instead if you're using `IHostingEnvironment`. More details can be found in [Static files in Asp.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

The above will filter `MyCol` on the values in the file.

You'll also need to perform your own error checking and validation if, for example, the file doesn't contain values which are convertible to `int`s.